# CloudBlob.CopyState is null after direct account-to-account copy completes

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Edit: Extended code sample to show how the `destinationBlob` is loaded.

We're making use of direct account to account copying to transfer a set of blobs. Because properties are overwritten when the process starts we monitor the destination blobs on an interval then set properties when the copy is complete. For the most part this process works fine.

However, for just a couple of these blobs, there is no copy state on the destination blob (`CloudBlob.CopyState` is `null`). These blobs do not exist before hand, they're created as a result of calling `CloudBlob.StartCopyAsync()`.

Here is some simplified code to outline how it works.

```cs
// Start copy operation
var operationId = await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(sourceBlobUrlWithSas));

...

// In a separate process, check the status after a delay, then repeat on an interval
var destinationBlob = await _destinationContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(blobName);

if (destinationBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Success) // <-- CopyState is null
{
    // Set properties
}
```

Microsoft docs indicate `CopyState` will be `null` when there is no copy state, but don't outline when that is. From my own experimentation, the destination blob seems to be created immediately, and the copy state seems remain on the blob for some time after an copy operation completes. When the issue occurs it's only a few minutes between starting the copy and checking the `CopyState`.

What could be the issue? Are there alternate methods of setting properties on the destination blob?

Comment: I think you can also include the `CopyState.Status == null` in the if statement, like `if (destinationBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Success || destinationBlob.CopyState.Status == null)`.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help because the `CopyState` property is returning `null`.

Comment: Then you can use the null-conditional operator, change the code to `if (destinationBlob.CopyState?.Status == CopyStatus.Success || destinationBlob.CopyState?.Status == null)`.

Comment: Hello Tom, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue ended up being due to a logic error whereby blobs would be 'touched' resulting in the copy state being removed. The documentation around the lifecycle of copy state data could certainly be better, though hopefully this insight helps others who encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `CopyState`, we need to run the method `CloudBlob.FetchAttributesAsync` at first. The method will return the blob's properties and metadata from server then we can get `CopyState`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-copy?tabs=dotnet11#copy-a-blob).

For example (I test with package `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`)

```
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            CloudBlob destBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReference(soureblob.Name);
            string copyId = await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(uri);
            await destBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Status of copy operation: {0}", destBlob.CopyState.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Completion time: {0}", destBlob.CopyState.CompletionTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes copied: {0}", destBlob.CopyState.BytesCopied.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Total bytes: {0}", destBlob.CopyState.TotalBytes.ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: Although excluded from the code sample, the blob is loaded using `BlobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync()` so the `CopyState` is already populated. As mentioned, this only occurs for a couple of blobs out of hundreds copied.

Comment: @Tom  COuld you please provide your whole code.

Comment: Code sample updated to show loading of `destinationBlob` to check `CopyState`.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 workarounds.

1.check the destination blob, whatever it's `copystatus` is successful or null, the code like below(here we're using the `null-conditional operator`, so no worries when the `CopyState` is null):

```
if (destinationBlob.CopyState?.Status == CopyStatus.Success || destinationBlob.CopyState?.Status == null)
{
   //codes to set properties
}
```

2.Another way is that you can create [a blob trigger azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#example), which targets the destination container. It means that when there is any blob uploaded/copied to destination container, the function will be triggered. So you can write your logic in the function.

**Note**: you can use [CloudBlockBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage) instead of `Stream` for the blob type in the code, so you can take use of `CloudBlockBlob` to add properites easily.

```
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
   //other code
}
```